# How to use dates on x axis with google chart api

Tags: php, api, google-visualization

This question has [already been addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020061/how-to-use-dates-in-x-axis-with-google-chart-api) but I would like to see some PHP code on actually doing this and also because I did not have the ability to comment so I was asked to 'restart' the thread.

I am trying to plot dates on the x-axis but my dates do not have the same frequency.

Here are some sample data points to have as an example:
Date:Value, 1/1/2009:100, 1/5/2009:150, 1/6/2009:165, 1/13/2009:200, 1/20/2009:350, 1/30/2009:500

I would like to see a chart that have the points separated relative to their actual time apart in days.  I am attempting to do this efficiently in PHP and would appreciate any advice.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some [good code here](http://walkertracker.com/api/docs/google-charts.php?username=ben).  No longer will my question be a tumbleweed!

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is a jQuery plotting library that looks very promising!